# Proof Verification: Possibilities for the rank of a composition of 2 transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

The following question came up on a recent exam that I took.

Let $U$, $V$ and $W$ be complex vector spaces such that $\dim V = 4$. Let $A$ be a linear transformation from $U$ to $V$ such that the dimension of the kernel of $A$ is 2. Let $B$ be a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$, and consider the transformation $BA$ from $U$ to $W$ such that the dimension of the kernel $BA$ is 3. List all possibilities of the dimension of the range (rank) of $BA$.

**Proposed Proof:**

We consider multiple cases by considering the dimension of the range of the transformation $A$. If rank$(A)$ = 0, then $A$ is the zero map. In this case, for every $u \in U$ such that, we have,
\begin{equation}
BA(u) = B(A(u)) = B(0_V) = 0_W.
\end{equation}
So, $BA$ is the zero map, and the rank is 0.

If rank$(A)$ is 1, we have that $BA$ is the zero map is $B$ is the zero map. In this case, rank$(BA) = 0$. Let $B$ not be a zero map. We claim that $BA$ must still be the zero map. Assume $BA$ isn't the zero map. Let $u \in R(A)$ such that $u \neq 0$, and $B(u) \neq 0$. Since $R(A)$ is a 1-dimensional subspace, we have that, any $v \in R(A)$, $v \neq 0$, is such that, $v = \alpha u, \alpha \neq 0$. Then, $B(v) = \alpha B(u) \neq 0$. Hence, the kernel of $BA$ remains of dimension 2 because all vectors outside of the kernel of $A$, which are mapped into $R(A)$, are mapped to non-zero vectors, a contradiction. Hence, $BA$ must be the zero map.

Now let rank$(A) = 2$. WLOG, let $B$ not be the zero map. Let $\beta = \{ v_1, v_2 \}$ be a basis for $R(A)$. Then,
\begin{equation}
B(R(A)) = span (R(A)) = \alpha_1 B(v_1) + \alpha_2 B(v_2),
\end{equation}
where $B(v_1) \neq 0$ or $B(v_2) \neq 0$. If both of them are non-zero, then, as before, the dimension of the kernal would not increase from 2 to 3. So, one of them is zero. If exactly one is zero, we will get rank$(BA) = 1$. If $B$ is the zero map the rank is $0$.

If rank$(A) = 3$, by arguments as above, a 1-dimensional subspace of $R(A)$ must be mapped to $0_W$. So, rank$(BA)$ is either $0, 1, 2$. If rank$(A)$ is 3, then rank$(BA)$ is either $0,1,2,3$.

I think the argument is correct, but, due to time constraints, I wrote a not so pristine proof. I think a lot of these cases could have been handled directly by extending basis of kernel of $B$ to kernel of $BA$, and referring to the rank-nullity theorem implies these are the only possibilities for rank$(BA)$. I have tried reproducing the proof by including only those details I wrote on the paper. There were some other details I wrote which I didn't end up using to complete the argument.

This quesion was for 10 points, so I am trying to see if I have at least some parts correct.

Comment: @amd Corrected.

Comment: It looks like you’re examining the rank of $B$, but your problem statement asks about the rank of $BA$. Aside from that why are you examining different cases for the rank of $A$? You’re given $\dim\ker A$, so you know its rank, too.

Comment: @amd We are not given that $U$ is a finite dimensional vector space. We're only given that $V$ is finite dimensional. I think your last statement will be true only when the rank-nullity theorem is applicable, for which we need the domain of $A$, $U$, to be finite dimensional.

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed that.

Comment: @amd As far as your first statement is conerned; yes, but if I consider various cases for rank$(A)$, that's equivalent to pinning down the dimension of the image of $U$ under $A$. Then determining the action of $BA$ boils down to determining the action of $B$ on the image of $U$ under $A$, which is denoted by $R(A)$. Since $R(A)$ is finite dimensional, we can now use the rank-nullity theorem, along with the argument that if $B$ is non-zero, it must map at least a one dimensional subspace of $R(A)$ to zero to ensure the kernel $BA$ increases from 2 to 3.

Comment: This is the gist of my I hope this makes sense. :/